# Nodejs application intermittently leaks memory when deployed to CF using SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

We are using mta to structure our application consisting of multiple micro-services.

Earlier we were deploying the micro-services to SAP Cloud Foundry using the CF CLI but recently switched to SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline for deployment using blue-green mode.

One of the micro-services is based on Nodejs.
If we use the CF CLI for deploying the nodejs microservice, it requires only 2 GB memory allocation.
The application gets deployed without any issue.

However, for the same aforesaid application, 2 GB isn't always suffice if we switch to the SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline for blue-green deployment.
Not everytime but intermittently the application deployment fails due to OUT OF MEMORY issue.
We even tried increasing the allocated memory to 4 GB but still it fails intermittently with the above issue.

We are not sure but looks like the aforementioned memory leakage is due to blue-green deployment mode by SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline.
Appreciate if someone can help us here to resolve this issue of memory leakage.
Please find below the logs.

```
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! errno 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! testapp@0.0.0 build-prod: `ng build`
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Exit status 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! 
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Failed at the testapp@0.0.0 build-prod script.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR!     /home/vcap/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T20_04_25_756Z-debug.log
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! errno 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! testapp@0.0.0 ci-build: `npm run build-prod`
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Exit status 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! 
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Failed at the testapp@0.0.0 ci-build script.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR!     /home/vcap/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T20_04_25_772Z-debug.log
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! errno 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! testapp@0.0.0 postinstall: `npm run ci-build`
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Exit status 137
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! 
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! Failed at the testapp@0.0.0 postinstall script.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 [STG/0] OUT npm ERR!     /home/vcap/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T20_04_25_807Z-debug.log
 [STG/0] OUT        [31;1m**ERROR**[0m Unable to build dependencies: exit status 137
 [STG/0] ERR Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 223 (out of memory)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first of all to not register `ci-build` as a post install script.
This should not be required. The pipeline will automatically invoke `npm run ci-build` after `npm install`. I think with your current configuration it is even executed twice in the build stage.

As the cf deployment also executes `npm install` also the `ci-build` will be triggered which should not be required as it was executed already before.